# Unresolved identifier

Tags: ios, swift

I keep getting an error saying that...

**'for message in json ["Messages"].arrayValue {'**

has an unresolved identifier?? Please can anyone help me with what this means and how/where I resolve the issue?

```
for message in json["Messages"].arrayValue {
                let newMessage = Message(data: message)
                if newMessage.sentTime = .stringValue < "01:00:00" {
                    self.filterMessages(newMessage)
                }
            }
```

The below section is what the above is referring to if that helps at all??

```
message = data["Message"].stringValue
    id = data["Id"].intValue
    showId = data["ProgramId"].intValue
    user = data["User"].stringValue

    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
    sentTime = dateFormatter.dateFromString(data["SentTime"].stringValue)!
```

Comment: where did you define json? or what is your json? Did you wanna use data instead of json?

Comment: Apart from the problem `< "01:00:00"` will never work reliably.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 let value = json["Messages"]
 for message in value {
            let newMessage = Message(data: message)
            if newMessage.sentTime = .stringValue < "01:00:00" {
                self.filterMessages(newMessage)
            }
        }
```

i hope it's work

Answer (score 0):

Iterate json array as

```
for message in json["Messages"] as? NSArray{
    let newMessage = Message(data: message)
    if newMessage.sentTime = .stringValue < "01:00:00" {
       self.filterMessages(newMessage)
    }
 }
```